# Surprisingly difficult limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Is there an easy way to prove that $|\operatorname{Re}(a_n)| \to \infty$ where $a_n=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)^n$?

Of course $|a_n| \to \infty$, but we have
$$
\operatorname{Re}(a_n)=2^{-n}\sum_{0 \leq k \leq [n/2]} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}7^k
$$
where $[n/2]$ stands for the integer part of $n/2$.

However I don't see how this could be computed differently, or estimated in order to prove the claim...

Comment: Asked and answered some years ago on Math Stack Exchange.  The result is nontrivial but can be proved in several ways using known techniques. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705877/an-exotic-sequence

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed hard!

Comment: Your definition of $a_n$ seems to be an absolute value, so it's already real. Did you mean to use parentheses? Also, use \left and \right to make them the right size, thus $$a_n = \left(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt7}{2}\right)^n.$$

Comment: Yes, I meant that!

Comment: And did you mean $|\operatorname{Re}(a_n)|\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry for this mess. The answer of @NoamD.Elkies is exactly answering this statement (and not the two previous iterations of my question, sorry).